# Loss reduction, but constant performance with CNN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I made a CNN with a reasonable loss curve, but the performance of the model does not improve. I have tried making the model larger, I am using three convolutional layers with batch norms.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Data]

Comment: Hi. You need to give more details regarding your problem. You also need to be more specific regarding your illustrations.